# Why doesn't my reputation increase even though I get upvoted? Bug?

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, votes

I've been noticing that though Votes in summary of my profile increases, the reputation doesn't increase and also it doesn't show up in profile. It used to before like +10 or +20 etc. I tried to google the problem and found there is an application to recalculate the reputation. It didn't work and still shows the same. Is it a bug? Or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have possibly hit the rep cap. You can only get 200 rep a day. The only exceptions are bounties and getting accepted.

Comment: And revoking of downvotes?

Comment: Thank you :) Does that mean those extra votes would never get counted?

Comment: @Ershad Nope. Anything over the rep cap will be forever ignored.

Comment: @muntoo Ah.. okay. Thank you :)